# Bookmarks thumbnails in Opera

Tags: opera-extension

is there any permission (like `chrome://favicon/`) that will allow me to access bookmark images?
so far, I'm only getting **Not allowed to load local resource:**
when trying to get bkm image

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to access such images.

Comment: any chance in the future you will allow access to *browser://bookmark-image* for read/write?... 'cause, that would be awesome :)

Comment: The idea sounds interesting also for me but I can't give you any precise answer yet. For sure there is a chance.